# Pearson Correlation Covariance Showing Positive when Negative Correlated

Tags: r, covariance, pearson-correlation

I'm trying to compute **Pearson correlation** for these two below. And it fits a linear line `y=1/3*(x)`. When I calculate covariance, I got 4.5 and standard deviation for x and y are 4.74 and 1.58 respectively, which ends up a positive coefficient. However, the slides I have tells me the covariance is -7.5 and the coefficient -1, which confuses me. Who is actually correct on this?

> x<-c(-3,-6,0,3,6)
>
> y<-c(1,-2,0,-1,2)

Comment: How do the slides justify that conclusion? If you plot those vectors you see that the correlation coefficient can't equal to -1. If this is an assignment, is there anything you might have missed in the briefing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x<-c(-3,-6,0,3,6)
y<-c(1,-2,0,-1,2)

cor(x,y, method = "pearson") # pearson correlation
[1] 0.6

cov(x,y) # covariance
[1] 4.5
```

you can also compute the covariance and pearson correlation manually to double check:

```
N <- length(x)
x_ <- mean(x)
y_ <- mean(y)

cova <- 0
for(i in 1:length(x))
{
  cova <- cova + ((x[i]-x_)*(y[i]-y_))/(N-1)
}

cova
[1] 4.5
```

or:

```
cova <- as.numeric((x-x_)%*%(y-y_)/(N-1))

cova
[1] 4.5
```

for the pearson correlation:

```
cova / (sqrt(var(x)*var(y)))
[1] 0.6
```